# Imported vue instance is undefined in created/mounted hooks after page reload

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to build in Vue a functionality that will perform autologin after user reloads the page. I'm importing vue instance to a module that sends the HTTP request. And I'm importing that module to main component of the app, in which I'm trying to call it from created/mounted hook. But the login module throws an error in regards to the imported vue instance "TypeError: Cannot read property '$http' of undefined" and indeed vue seems to be undefined at that point. What am I doing wrong?

The login function works perfectly when it is called e.g. from a button. Also the mounted/created autologin works (!) if the page is refreshed by dev server after any changes are saved to the code. It just doesn't work after browser-triggered reload.

```
// main.js - entry point
export const vue = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
});

// App.vue - main app component
<script>
    import { login } from './controllers/loginController';
    export default {
        created: function () { //tried mounted as well
        login('dummy@dummy.com', 'dummy', 2);
        }
    };
</script>

// loginController.js
import { vue } from '../main';
export const login = function (email, password, reportID = null) {
    vue.$http
        .post('login/', { email: email, password: password, reportID: reportID })
        .then(...)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is wrong ?**

you are importing `Vue` on `loginController.js` so now the engine will go to the specific path and compile that file and only then move to the next instruction ... so when compiling the file `main.js` it will reach your created function and find the `login` function call inside it ... login function is defined but the `vue` inside it is still under compiling ... so it is still `undefined`

**How can i fix this ?**

i would recommend using the `login` inside your vue instance since it is the proper way :

```js
//App.vue

created() {
function login(email, password, reportID = null) {
    this.$http
        .post('login/', { email: email, password: password, reportID: reportID })
        .then(() =>{...})
    login('dummy@dummy.com', 'dummy', 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution indeed works. I was hoping to extract the code elsewhere, as the login procedure will be obviously used also in other place. One thing still bothers me - shouldn't the `created` (and especially `mounted`!) hooks be when everything is already compiled?

Comment: PS. In order to avoid boilercode I came to the conclusion that I can pass `this.$http` to the login function as a parameter and use it inside while avoiding import of vue instance. It seems to work correctly. Do you see any contraindications for such solution?

Comment: @Eggon Responding to your first question "shouldn't the created (and especially mounted!) hooks be when everything is already compiled?"  : asnwer : no ... those  are the component hooks for `App.vue` they get triggered once the component is being created / mounted and each component has its own hooks so they are related to the component it self they don't know if your instance is compiled or not yet ...

Comment: @Eggon "Do you see any contraindications for such solution? " No that's better than the old setup and since it is working fine with no errors you should be fine

Comment: Thanks! I understand that hooks are related to components, but we're talking about main/parent component here. How can the main component be ready (or any actually? but main especially) if vue instance is not?

Comment: Exactly it cannot be ready before everything inside it is compiled (including components) so the login was called inside App which is a component inside the parent root ... so the engine goes and looks for login function and start a new execution context ... when reading `vue` variable inside it he throws an error because it is not defined yet it is under compiling ... hope it does make sense

Comment: Ok, guess it makes sense, I don't know about vue's internal architecture, so I just imagined it being different with the vue engine being compiled first and then components that are attached. It's a pity then taht there are no hooks on the instance itself as a whole. Anyway, thanks for the help again! Cheers!